# SetInterval depending on when i run it

Tags: setinterval

We have a side that has a server time. I want to check the server time every 1 ms and when it goes to a certain second and ms i want a button to be confirm. I do this with setInterval. The problem with this is that if I run my script via bookmarks 1 minute before the wanted time and 5 minutes before the wanted  time, there is a difference on the time it confirms the button although the time I want is the exactly the same.
Any ideas will be appreciate!

The code i have made as far is this:

```
javascript:var currentTime=$("#serverTime").text().split(":");
var currentSec=currentTime[2];
var currentMs=new Date().getMilliseconds();
function checkTime(){
var currentTime=$("#serverTime").text().split(":");
var currentHours = currentTime[0];
var currentMins = currentTime[1];
var currentSec=currentTime[2];
var currentMs=new Date().getMilliseconds();
if((currentHours == 13)(currentMins == 30)&&(currentSec==00)&&(currentMs>0)&&(currentMs<15)){
document.forms[0].submit.click()
}
}
var confirm=setInterval("checkTime()",1);
```

So i want the form to be submited at 13:30:00 and 00 to 15 ms with this script that I run it on a website(with the form I want to submit) via bookmarks. The problem is that if I run it 2 hours before the time the form will be submited some ms or sec later than if I run the script 10 mins before 13:30:00. 
Any ides?

Comment: Every millisecond is quite a load on your server. Can you explain your problem in more detail? Provide relevant code as well.

Comment: 1. format your code better please; 2. as already stated, check the server _every millisecond_? You sure?

Comment: It checks every milliseconds the server hours/minutes/seconds. Also it checks every milliseconds the milliseconds that javascript provides with: new Date().getMilliseconds();
*edit code again

Comment: Yeah but the whole roundtrip for a request will be way more slower than 1ms, why do you need such a time-critical check? Do every second if you need to check, or every 3/400 ms, but not every single ms!